# VBA subtract date and times

Tags: excel, vba, date

```
Dim dtmStart As Date, dtmEnd As Date, dblDuration As Double
dtmStart = "1900/01/01 08:10:00"
dtmEnd = "1900/01/03 21:16:00"
dblDuration = DateDiff("hh:mm", dtmEnd, dtmStart)
'dblDuration = dtmEnd - dtmStart
MsgBox Format(dblDuration, "hh:mm")
```

How would I subtract two dates in a "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss" format? I tried both methods above and neither work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim dtmStart As Date, dtmEnd As Date, dblDuration As Double
    dtmStart = "1900/01/01 08:10:00"
    dtmEnd = "1900/01/03 21:16:00"
    dblDuration = dtmEnd - dtmStart
    MsgBox Application.Text(dblDuration, "[hh]:mm")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! The square brackets around hours is what I needed :|

Comment: @JFC - even comments have limits

Answer (score 0):

Well I am a simple Dane, and I like it simple, so I just did it like this:

```
Dim dtmStart As Date, dtmEnd As Date, dblDuration As Date

Start:  'STARTTIME
        dtmStart = Time

Slut:           
        'SLUTTIDEN
        dtmEnd = Time
        dblDuration = dtmEnd - dtmStart
        Debug.Print "Modul 1 Slut  " & Time; " Run = "; dblDuration
```